# How to Import/Query the 'EntityHistory' Object Data Through Data Loader in salesforce

Tags: soql, data-loader, sosl

i have some records/data, i mention in Excel File is in below, and **i need How to Query the Records from "EntityHistory" Object...**

please Help me i will try my developer Edition.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert [`EntityHistory`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_entityhistory.htm) records at all (they represent field history changes).

Note also:

> This object is unavailable beginning with API version 8.0

You can perform SOQL against object-specific tables like [`AccountHistory`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_accounthistory.htm), but you cannot insert them either.

You may also be interested in how to [query](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=field_history_workflow_examples.htm&type=0) Field Audit Trail's `FieldHistoryArchive` table.